# MongoDb RegEx search in object array

Tags: arrays, regex, mongodb

I have an existing data structure in my collection which basically looks like this (simplified):

```
[
  { items: [
    { id: '000', value: 'string' },
    { id: '001', value: 1234 },
    { id: '002', value: true },
    ...
  ] },
  { items: [
    { id: '000', value: 'another string' },
    { id: '001', value: 2345 },
    { id: '002', value: false },
    ...
  ] },
  ...
]
```

Now I want to search for values of certain `id`s (dynamically selected by the user), matching a regular expression (entered by the user and properly escaped to actually search for a substring only). As I need to extract the values for the mentioned `id`s I am using a aggregation pipeline starting with a `$match`:

```
{ $match: {
    items: { $elemMatch: {
        item_id: { $in: ['000', '002'] },
        item_data: { $regex: 'e', $options: 'i' }
    } }
} }
```

I expected that both documents are returned - the first one due to the matching 'e' in 'true' and the second for the matching 'e' in 'another'. But I realized that the `$regex` operator only works for string values and simply ignores all other types. What I want is to convert other types to strings (via `$toString` or something similar), so I can also search in numbers and other data types as well. Is this possible using `$elemMatch` or do I need another operator?

Comment: An "aside": is your filtering of this data always going to be in a manner that assumes it is a string? If so then I'd opt to just convert the actual data. If not, but that's still a frequent operation, I'd still consider storing an additional copy in the stringified format for searching. What you're asking for directly is doable but cumbersome (at least the approaches that come to mind for me)

Comment: No it's not always a string. In fact the data is stored by the user from a 'dynamic' mask which allows for the different data types. I am displaying the data in a table, which allows for filtering for each column (using the stored data type) or by searching for a substring (which is what I am trying to achieve in the request) in any of the displayed columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `$or` criteria in `$map` to make an array of booleans. Then use `$anyElementTrue` to return the whole document. You can wrap the whole thing in `$expr` and put it in `find`. And yes, you will need `$toString` to convert non-string `value` fields for `$regexMatch`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$anyElementTrue": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$items",
        "as": "i",
        "in": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "$in": [
                "$$i.id",
                [
                  "000",
                  "002"
                ]
              ]
            },
            {
              "$regexMatch": {
                "input": {
                  "$toString": "$$i.value"
                },
                "regex": "e",
                "options": "i"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nINRaN6dR_p)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The query works great! I only had to change the `$or` to `$and` as the regular expression only should match when the id matches as well.